# Connect Prisma with AWS Aurora Serverless (MySQL) Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, prisma, aws-aurora-serverless

Does anybody know how to integrate Prisma with AWS Aurora serverless (MySQL) database?

I know that Prisma supports AWS Aurora severless, I just don't know the best way to connect the two.

I have read this [article](https://dev.to/prisma/prisma-migrate-with-aws-aurora-serverless-53g7), discussing using a jump box, but according to AWS this is a [better solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/toward-a-bastion-less-world).

Also, I have seen Prisma has [Prisma Data Proxy](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-data-platform#prisma-data-proxy) in early access.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've figured this out and got it working now, as soon as I get time I will post a detailed description.

Comment: how did you do ?